# Is oracle client required on remote machine to connect to a database on another machine?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to connect to a oracle database using jdbc.. 
if i gave the connection url in below format, i am getting ora-12505 error.

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:sid

but if i give the connection string in below format, i am getting an error like "java.sql.SQLException: I o exception : The network adapter could not establish the connection"

> dbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=SCAN-LISTENER-NAME)(PORT=1530))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=Service-name)))

is oracle client needed on my remote machine? or is it due to connectivity b/n host and remote systems. I tested the connectivity using telnet and it is fine..

kindly provide ur inputs

Comment: Use `lsnrctl status` on the database host to see what services are registered. Then double-check your JDBC URL.

Comment: Thanks Mat. My doubt here is, do i require oracle client on my remote machine?

Comment: Not for JDBC thin connection.